# How do I make a div that stays in a fixed position regardless of where you are on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

Case example: I have a long list of items, and when I put my mouse over this div changes to that picture of that item. No matter where you scroll to, the div remains in a fixed position.

Sort of like a frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the CSS property `position:fixed`.

Example: `<div id="items" style="position: fixed; top: 20px; right: 20px">Hello there!</div>`

Answer (score 2):

> the div remains in a fixed position.

`position: fixed`? Test it [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html).

Answer (score 2):

For newer browsers you can use `position:fixed` to make an element follow the window when you scroll.

If you need to be compatible with older browsers, you would need a Javascript that gets the scroll offset from the window and changes the coordinates of an absolutely positioned element.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning:

```
<body>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That keeps the element in a fixed position relative to the page, I think that the OP want's it relative to the window.

Comment: @Guffa - I don't think it is clear in message, I saw two fixed position answers and posted this to provide an alternative as I am unclear of his desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about div in fixed position? If you want to this the div by css itself, you can use the paramater like

```
height:0px;
left:0px;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
width:0px;
z-index:1;
```

Comment: That keeps the element in a fixed position relative to the page, I think that the OP want's it relative to the window.

Comment: Instead of fixed, we can absolute also